# Variable not being passed into WordPress loop

Tags: loop

In my WordPress custom post type loop only want to pull in from three posts 5171, 5167 and 5165.

If I do:

```
'post__in' => array(5171,5167,5165),
```

The loop outputs the values for those three correctly.

If I do:

```
'post__in' => array($my_share),
```

It only outputs the values for **5171**. However **$my_share** equals **5171,5167,5165**. If I do `echo $my_share` it also shows **5171,5167,5165**.

Is there any obvious reason why $my_share is only passing the first value into the post__in array or anyway around that issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $my_share echoes as "5171,5167,5165" then it is a string not an array...

In other words `array($string)` does not equal `array(integer,integer,integer)` even if `$string` equals "integer,integer,integer" because array treats $string as a single value with further values separated by commas.

You could use `post__in => explode(",", $my_share),` to convert the string into an array while passing it... otherwise you could try just using `post__in => $my_share,` and it *might* be converted into an array for you (but not sure without delving deep into the code to look.)

Comment: Live saver! Continued searching and actually ended up finding, "explode(",", $my_share)" however passed over it since I tried doing, array(explode(",", $my_share)) which of course didn't work, and now makes better sense why. Thanks so much!!